# C# Linq Net Core: Exclude Words which contain search term

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

How do I conduct String Not Contains 'paraphrase key term' in Linq Net Core 2?

For this one, trying to acquire in the list which do Not contain 'ag' in the Product Name.

```
foreach (var product in Products().Where(c=>c.ProductName.NotContains("ag")))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
foreach (var product in Products().Where( c => !c.ProductName.Contains("ag")))
```

Thats it

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
foreach (var product in Products().Where(c=> !c.ProductName.Contains("ag")))
```